# How to get raw byte data of http header for requests sent using QNetworkRequest

Tags: qt

I am using `QNetworkRequest` in order to perform https requests. I would like to debug it and see ALL contents of the http header that is constructed by this class before it's sent out to https server.

So far I do this:

```
QString header_list;
QList<QByteArray> headerList = request->rawHeaderList();
foreach(QByteArray head, headerList)
   header_list += head + ": " + request->rawHeader(head) + "\n";
```

This results in string that contains all parts of header that I explicitly set using `setRawHeader`, but it doesn't show the values that are default or added by the class itself, without my intervention.

Normally I would use `tcpdump` to see what my applications tries to send to server, but it's using SSL so I can't.

I really would like to see the "real" header that actually goes out, which is for some reason well hidden inside of the class.

Is there any simple way to retrieve it so I can see what http header is my application using?

Answer (score 3):

The HTTP headers are set [deep inside](https://github.com/qtproject/qtbase/blob/5.6/src/network/access/qhttpnetworkconnection.cpp#L248) Qt network module. You can't get them.
Default headers following:

```
Content-Length: 42 // if there is outgoing data
Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive // if there is http proxy
Connection: Keep-Alive
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: ru-RU,en,* // depend on system locale
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0
Host: www.google.com
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded // if there is outgoing data, depend on data type
```